# How to setup connection between React Native app and Thingspeak (cloud service)?

Tags: react-native, cloud, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm a beginner in **react native** and I'm working on a mobile app for school. Within it, I need to send and receive data (draw graphs) from the cloud. We use cloud services from **Mathworks - Thingspeak**. Would you please advise me on how to start this communication? Is it necessary to set this communication on every screen where graphs will be displayed or send data? Is it possible to use write & read API keys for this task?

Thank you for every answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use REST API for communication,

For read: https://www.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/readdata.html

For write: https://www.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/writedata.html

There are example requests on both pages.

You don't need to install a separate package, you can do it with `fetch`

Let me know if you succeeded, or I can help again!

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer :) Right now I'm able to display the data - last uploaded value in a field, however, it does not update automatically.  I'm using 'useEffect()' from react before fetching the data. Is there any way to fetch data periodically, for example once or twice per a minute?

Comment: You can do it with setInterval(fetchData, 60000), but ThingSpeak also has MQTT API, so you can subscribe to a channel and get the updates immediately. It would be a better solution.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! :)